# Unable to create maintenance plan

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2017, connectivity, maintenance-plans

When trying to create a maintenance plan locally on two prod servers through SSMS, I receive this error:

[image: Maintenance plan creation]

No such error occurs on my UAT system. They're all running SQL Server 2017 (14.0.3162.1), and they were all installed with the same feature set. The UAT machine is Windows 10, while the prod servers are Windows Server 2016.

Which components/features specifically need to be installed such that I can create a maintenance plan?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not installed express edition because as far as I recall I had that error there sometime back.

Also please check if you have got SSIS component installed. I do not use maintainece plans but per my knowledge since those use part of SSIS I guess that component is needed to run the maintenance plan

Comment: Thanks. I've just installed SSIS, but that hasn't resolved the issue. On the Express edition, are you suggesting that I need to install that? If so, what specifically?